# IE8 error res://ieframe.dll/preview.js while printing

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

here is my code and while i am executing it i am getting this error

```
res://ieframe.dll/preview.js
at line:14
```

Code:

```
var divToPrint1 = $('#PrintDoc').html();
var newWin = window.open('Share Certificate #001', 'Print-Window', 'width=10px,height=10px');
newWin.document.open();
newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print();">' + divToPrint1 + '</body></html>');
newWin.document.close();
```

Can any one help me in this?
Please don't give solution for reseting IE setting through internet option. It's not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: http://iefaq.info/index.php?action=artikel&cat=48&id=133&artlang=en

greetings,
s3lbstlaut